# Ethereum Node on Azure Virtual Machine (windows) remote access

Tags: azure, firewall, go-ethereum

I've a Windows Server VM on Azure where geth is running quite good (no mining, just node).

Now, the "start command" is:

```
geth --rpcapi "eth,web3,db,net,personal,admin" --rpcaddr "10.0.0.4" --port "30303" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcport "8545" --rpc --ws --wsaddr "10.0.0.4" --nat "any"
```

From the Virtual Machine itself, I can go on the browser and write

```
 http://10.0.0.4:8545
```

And everything is working. 
From "outside" I try to access to

```
http://virtualmachineip:8545
```

And I get a Timeout, event if the firewall rule I configured is TOTALLY permissive like:

[image]

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: be carefull, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671277/is-it-secure-to-run-public-ethereum-node/52076421#52076421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it's not enough to enable the firewall rule on Azure portal.

In order to "open" the machine, also the "in virtual machine" configuration is needed.

So:

- Inside the virtual machine:

  1) virtual defender firewall

  2) Advanced

  3) Inbound rules

  4) Add rule on port 8545
- In azure portal, on Virtual Machine page

  1) Networking

  2) Add inbound rule

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is no firewall to blocking the access traffic.

Then you can try to `geth` with `--rpcaddr "0.0.0.0"` to allow all address when you want to access from outside.

Also, check if network connectivity is normal by running telnet command from the host you access to node:

```
telnet virtualmachineip 8545
```

For more reference, see this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32111063/connecting-to-ethereum-node-in-web-browser) and [Common Problems With Connectivity.](https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/connecting.html)